# How to make notifications stop saying "Time Sensitive"

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

All my calendar event notifications say "Time Sensitive". How can I make them not say that anymore?

Comment: Did you read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439430/how-does-macos-calendar-determine-if-an-event-is-time-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide this title on macOS by unchecking the "Allow time sensitive alerts" toggle. Notifications will appear exactly the same but without the "TIME SENSITIVE" title.

The same thing works on iOS as well

[image]
[image]